# How to view a specific command executed in terminal by time?

Tags: command-line

I need to view a command in history by time executed in Ubuntu 12.04 .

So , I could know each command , the time it has been executed .

That help when you want to view a command that you should execute in a specific time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to active history command by time display :

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

You can check your command history in terminal :

```
history
```